# How to get image pixel values faster in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, pixel

I've been trying to get image pixel values in different ways in React Native, but the only way that works currently is using the modules '@thebeka/react-native-pixel-color'. The modules extracts the color of the specific position in the format of '#FFFFFF'. Then I need to separate the color into red, green, blue components. It works fine when the image height and width are small (28, 56, etc.) but run for like nearly a minute if the height and width are 224. The reason to do this is to use the data as an input for an ONNX model to process it. Here is the code:

```
import GetPixelColor from '@thebeka/react-native-get-pixel-color';
.
.
.
interface RGBImage {
    r: number[][];
    g: number[][];
    b: number[][];
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
    .
    .
    .
    const cvtImg = async (imageHeight: number, imageWidth: number, base64: string) => {
      try {
        GetPixelColor.init(base64)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('INITIALIZE: ', response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error 1: ');
          console.log(err);
        });

        const batchSize = 28; // Adjust the batch size as needed

        const channels = 3;
        const img: RGBImage = {
          r: new Array(imageHeight).fill([]).map(() => new Array(imageWidth)),
          g: new Array(imageHeight).fill([]).map(() => new Array(imageWidth)),
          b: new Array(imageHeight).fill([]).map(() => new Array(imageWidth)),
        };
        const promises: any[] = [];

        const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        for (let y = 0; y < imageHeight; y += batchSize) {
          for (let x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += batchSize) {
            const batchPromises = [];

            for (let i = y; i < Math.min(y + batchSize, imageHeight); i++) {
              for (let j = x; j < Math.min(x + batchSize, imageWidth); j++) {
                const promise = await GetPixelColor.pickColorAt(i, j)
                  .then((color) => {
                    // Extract RGB components from the pixel color
                    let r = (parseInt(color.slice(1), 16) >> 16) & 255;
                    let g = (parseInt(color.slice(1), 16) >> 8) & 255;
                    let b = (parseInt(color.slice(1), 16)) & 255;

                    // Store the color information in the corresponding channel subarrays
                    img.r[i][j] = r;
                    img.g[i][j] = g;
                    img.b[i][j] = b;
                    console.log('Position:', i, j, 'Color:', color);
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error 3: ');
                    console.log(err);
                  });

                batchPromises.push(promise);
                await delay(0.00001);
              }
            }

            promises.push(Promise.all(batchPromises));
          }
        }

        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('IMAGE: ', img);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error 4: ');
          console.log(err);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error converting image:', error);
        return null;
      }
    };
    
    .
    .
    .

    return (
      .
      .
      .
    );
  }

export default App;

.
.
.
```

Solutions to get image pixel values faster

Comment: The delay function seems to be unnecessary?

Comment: If I remove the delay function, it will return the error: Excessive number of pending callbacks.

Comment: I use Jpeg-js to retrieve pixel data. I'm not sure if it will be helpful, but you can give it a try.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js